# How do I read this figure on the sqlite documentation?

Tags: sqlite

I'm unsure how to read this figure to [Create a table in sqlite.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7MjY.png) Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reads/is interpreted as follows :-

1. **CREATE** is mandatory
2. **TEMP** or **TEMPORARY** (one or the other) is optional
3. **TABLE** is mandatory
4. **IF NOT EXISTS** is optional
5. the schema name is optional and if used must be followed by a period
6. Then you can either follow the AS SELECT statement route or the column definitions route.
7. If taking the column definitions route **(** is mandatory, followed by 1 or more column definitions separated by a comma, then by 0 or more comma separated table constraints followed by a mandatory ) and then optionally followed by **WITHOUT ROWID**.